# React Context API - form input is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to build simple todo application with new context API but I'm having a hard time trying to debug why my input value is undefined.

I don't quite understand how to execute a function provided by Provider and pass arguments to it.

here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
const AppContext = React.createContext();

class AppProvider extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      todoList: [{ text: "first test element", isCompleted: false }]
    };
  }

  addTodo = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.target.value);
    this.setState({
      todoList: [
        ...this.state.todoList,
        { text: e.target.value, isCompleted: false }
      ]
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { todoList, uniqueId } = this.state;
    return (
      <AppContext.Provider
        value={{ todoList, addTodo: this.addTodo }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </AppContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

const Consumer = AppContext.Consumer;

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: "" };
  }
  render() {
    return <AppProvider>
        <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
            <h1 className="App-title">TodoList</h1>
          </header>
          <Consumer>
            {state => <form onSubmit={state.addTodo}>
                <input type="text" />
                <button type="submit" onSubmit={state.addTodo}>
                  Add Todo
                </button>
              </form>}
          </Consumer>
          <Consumer>
            {val => (
              <ul>
                {val.todoList.map((item, index) => (
                  <li key={index}>{item.text}</li>
                ))}
              </ul>
            )}
          </Consumer>
        </div>
      </AppProvider>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

Sorry if my questions is trivial but I've been trying to solve it for quite a bit and I can't find what's wrong.

Comment: Not the answer but you could use this syntax over the one you're currently using:
this.setState({
      todoList: this.state.todoList.concat({ text: e.target.value, isCompleted: false })
    });

Comment: @LordAlpaca thanks i will use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just had some issues with how your form was sending the value through. Also, you should try decouple your events and your state, as shown in the working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/ly83lz4wnm).

Comment: hey thanks a lot. i have two more questions if you don't mind me asking:
- why do yo use arrow function inside onClick event, is it better than my approach?
- i can't find anywhere a reason why sometime people wrap arrow function in react in parenthesis () and sometimes in block {}, what the reason behind this?

Comment: 1.) It's actually better to define a function on the class and use that, since the way I did it, a new function is created every time it renders. I just did it for brevity. 2.) The second way is fine, and usually preferred.